# How to initiate login prompts

Tags: sustainsys-saml2

I'm refactoring an old webforms application to use this saml library to handle authentication.
I don't have any previous experience setting this sort of thing up so I am not familiar with the terminology.

After struggling for a bit modifying the example configuration elements so they would stop producing errors, my application now starts up like it used to seemingly uninfluenced by any of the new configuration.

I am under the impression that it should redirect to the signOnUrl configured in the sustainsys.saml2 identityProviders configuration, but I cannot see any evidence of that happening.

I realize its difficult to debug this without more context, but I'm hoping I am missing some really fundamental aspect that I'm completely oblivious to and someone can help me out.

For example I didn't see it anywhere in the documentation but I tried changing my authentication mode from "None" to "Forms" and then providing my signOnUrl as the loginUrl.  That didn't help.  (Also I find it strange that authentication mode was "None" for an application that sure as hell did require you to log in, so maybe that's a clue to someone more knowledgeable about this than I am.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are mentioning authentication mode etc. I assume that you are using the Sustainsys.Saml2.HttModule package.

In that case, navigate to `/Saml2/SignIn` to initiate the sign in process.